# Baofeng UV-82 Dual-Band (2m/70cm) HT Channel Clear Error

Tags: ht, baofeng

After clearing channels (menu option #28) to free them up for use, I have found that they become completely unusable for future frequencies. Switching back from VFO to channel mode and trying to go to those channels merely skips them and goes to the next one available. Clearing them and attempting to set them to a frequency just makes the channels unusable. Am I not supposed to 'clear' the channels first or is this a bug that others are experiencing?

I had been following [these instructions](http://www.miklor.com/COM/UV_ProgMem.php) to 'clear' the channels, but it seems to have the effect of deleting the channels.

Comment: Yeah, in general programming via PC is much less of a hassle. The cable is fairly cheap.

Comment: @Amber can you link to the cable? I'm not sure which one I need.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Cable-Baofeng-UV-5R-Driver/dp/B008RZJHJU/ref=pd_bxgy_e_img_y - the listing says UV-5R but it's the same cable.

Comment: Also yeah, as previously mentioned by @RonJ. - use CHIRP, the open source programming software. It's a lot nicer than the software the manufacturer ships.

Comment: @Amber I bought that cable but unfortunately it only shows up identified under USB not under ports, despite which drivers I use. I think that cable doesn't work with CHIRP. Arg....

Comment: @Amber Hmm seems a bunch of Chinese companies counterfeited Prolific USB-to-Serial chips and now Prolific has disabled a bunch of their drivers from working. I can't connect to my radio using Windows 7, Mac OS X, nor Ubuntu Linux. No good drivers apparently. Arg....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I can't duplicate the issue, I have seen periodic eccentric behavior with the Baofeng HT memory locations. The solution was to use a PC and program the radio with the free [CHIRP software](http://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/Home). Programming cable required.

Comment: Well, I've got the cable and the CHIRP daily build - but it won't see my radio. Arg....

Comment: Hmm seems a bunch of Chinese companies counterfeited Prolific USB-to-Serial chips and now Prolific has disabled a bunch of their drivers from working. I can't connect to my radio using Windows 7, Mac OS X, nor Ubuntu Linux. No good drivers apparently. Arg....

Comment: @Dan yes there are counterfeit FTDI and Prolific chips that will not work after a "Windows Update" update. The solution is to rollback to an older version of the driver and prevent Windows from ever updating that device driver.

Comment: Windows 7 would not let me roll back the driver, but I was able to finally get it to work in Windows 8 (I also tried Mac OS X 10.8 and 10.9 to no avail).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to be "on" a channel to set it - hence why clearing a channel removes your ability to "go" to it. When you are setting a channel, you'll input the number of the channel you want to set via the numeric pad, and it will be saved to whatever channel you enter, after which you'll be able to "go" to that channel.

Comment: Yes, but it seems I can't set the channel after deleting/clearing it.

Comment: What happens when you enter the number to set it?

Comment: Rather than saying 'confirm' like it should, it just beeps.

Comment: So you enter the number, then press Menu, and it just beeps? Is this after entering the channel number the first time or the second time?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many times. Once I delete a channel (menu #28), I can't confirm a new frequency for that channel in menu #27. I'm following [these instructions exactly as printed](http://www.miklor.com/COM/UV_ProgMem.php) (it worked fine for channel 000 but not for any after that).

Comment: Huh, okay, that's really odd. Yeah, I'd suggest trying it with the cable then; maybe there's something glitchy in the -82's firmware?

Comment: I'm thinking so. If there is a solution I'm open, but moreso I'm thinking this question will be a good Google search hit for others who will probably have the same issue and they can learn that the solution is to use a programming cable and CHIRP software.